# Include .swc folder in .gitignore for Next.js 12 projects?

Tags: next.js, gitignore

I just started working with Next.js 12 on a fresh project. When I ran `next`, a folder called .swc was automatically generated for me. I was wondering do I include this folder inside my .gitignore file like the .next folder?

Comment: I believe you should be able to safely gitignore the `.swc` folder. Related GitHub issue: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/38270.